# Calling ID of a database object Given the name

Tags: mysql

How would I get the ID of an object given its name/title?

Or similarly, get my description of it given its name in mysql?

Elaboration:

Let's say I assign Bob ID 1, Sam to ID 2, Cindy to ID 3

How do I call for their ID in proper mysql syntax if I give their name? What I want returned is their ID #

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the ID? what object?

Comment: Could you please elaborate with an example as to what you want, thanks.

Comment: Based on your *Elaboration*, currently given answers are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE title='my_title';
```

The object that is returned will contain the ID.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID FROM yourtablehere WHERE name='yournamehere';
```